# Java emulation of a vt220 terminal for screen scraping

Tags: java, screen-scraping, scrape

I have to do a screen scraping of a vt200 telnet connection using Java 1.6.

I have tried to cheat and use a simple telnet connection with InputStrem and OutputStream but the server is picky and, when it discovers that I am not a vt220 termina with 80 columns it closes the connection.

I am searching for an opensource or free library but I am not able to find one.

Can you help me?

Thanks,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) project supports the Telnet protocol.  The included [TerminalOptionTypeHandler](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TerminalTypeOptionHandler.html) looks like the correct way to support a specific terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I have missed that class. Now it works but I need to filter escape sequences, but this is another story!